# Dynamic QResource loading in Pyside

Tags: qt, resources, pyside

I'm using PySide and trying to dynamically re-skin UIs.

This seems to be working for when switching between stylesheets, but not for values set on Widgets themselves.

I'm using relative paths in the CSS like so:

```
background-image: url(:/icons/images/magnifier.png)
```

I can apply these CSS styles, using py files compiled from qrc files like so:

```
execfile(pyResourceFilePath, globals())
with open(cssFilePath, 'r') as f:
    css = f.read()
topWidget.setStyleSheet(css)
```

...which is a bit kludgy, but works.

However if I try using these relative paths when creating widgets:

```
icon = QtGui.QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(
    QtGui.QPixmap(":/icons/images/arrow-expand.gif"), 
    QtGui.QIcon.Normal, 
    QtGui.QIcon.Off
)
execfile(pyResourceFilePath, globals())
```

The images do not appear.

Using absolute paths in the above makes the images display , so it seems to be something with how the widgets understand where to look for resources.

I've tried fiddling with *QtCore.QResource.registerResource(pyResourceFilePath)*, but haven't had any success there either.

Any ideas?

### Edit:

After some conversation, it becomes apparent that the resources in the pixmaps need some sort of update (which I guess is really what the CSS is doing when I apply that).

What would be an efficient way to update any existing pixmaps with the same paths but under a new resource?

Comment: Why are you using `execfile` on a module, rather than just importing it? And surely the module needs to be imported **before** you reference the resource paths?

Comment: I suppose I could do a dynamic import, but the idea is that I only want to import the resources on demand -- if I have several styles/resource packages available, I only want to bring in the one the user requests or switches to.

Comment: In your example code, you try to reference a resource path **before** loading the resource. Why do you expect this to work? (And just to pre-empt one possible answer to this: if your real code does something different, maybe you should consider posting an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: That's correct; I'm setting a relative path to a resource before loading the resource.
I expect this to work because it seems to work with stylesheets -- though I should try hard-coding a style (rather than loading it dynamically) before importing the resource, to verify.

Comment: The other reason I believe this is possible is becuase QResource seems to hint at this ability, via the registerResource classmethod.  At least that's what I've gleaned from the docs (under Dynamic Resource Loading), though the implementation is a bit fuzzy to me.

Comment: The technology that underpins stylesheets has built-in support for dynamic updates. But you are wrong to assume such support exists for *all* Qt classes. If you create pixmaps from a resource, and then change the resource, you will have to update the pixmaps yourself. It will not happen automatically.